# Question on Limits from Spivak [Chapter 5 Question 39(3)]

Tags: limits, trigonometry

> We have to calculate
>   $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x\sin^2x)$

What I tried:
$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x\sin^2x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^2)\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)(\sin^2x)$

This is where I am stuck. In the above equation $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^2)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)(\sin^2x)=0$.

How do I proceed now? I mean how do I know whether $0$ will be approached faster or $∞$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That limit does not exist. If we had $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin^2(x)=l$ for some $l\in\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$, then, for any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$, we would have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\sin^2(x_n)=l$. But

- if $x_n=n\pi$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\sin^2(x_n)=0$;
- if $x_n=n\pi+\frac\pi2$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\sin^2(x_n)=\infty$.

Comment: Moral: Have confidence in yourself. The book may have an error, or may have a deliberately misleading Q to test you.